# How to get my .bat file to run a java command

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to run a simple batch file that navigates to a folder location and runs a java command.  What I have now won't run the command.

```
@echo on

set /p DIR="C:\Application\dir_to_run_from"

dir %DIR%

java -cp file.jar com.myCompany.db.collector.Collector
```

Right now I'm just getting the path printed when I run the command.

Comment: You tried moving the file.jar to the same folder ?

Comment: @berry120 he's specifying it as the classpath. If there's no main class specified in the manifest `-jar` won't work.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the meaning of `set /p`.

Comment: @WChargin Good point, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set /p` does not set the path. `p` stands for `prompt`. Usually, you'll use it like this:

```
set /p ANIMAL=Enter your favorite animal:
```

Instead, you probably just want to replace the first line with this:

```
cd "C:\Application\dir_to_run_from"
```

This will `cd` (change directory) to the directory you want to use. (You should change the second line to just `dir` if you take this route.)

Alternatively, you could replace the last line with this:

```
java -cp %DIR%\file.jar com.myCompany.db.collector.Collector
```